# Bootstrap 3.3.1 carousel animation not working with LESS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, less, carousel

I am working on a Bootstrap template that I am building on the Bootstrap 3.3.1 LESS files compiled on the go (as a temporary solution) with less.min.js. The problem is when I try to flip slides of the Bootstrap carousel they do so with no animation. Chrome Dev tools gave me this:

```
.carousel-inner > .item {
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000;
}
```

As you can see there is not -webkit-transition line for some reasons.

Switching to bootstrap.css or replacing the carousel.less file with that from v3.3.0 resolves the issue. Is it a Bootstrap issue or is it something on my side?

Answer (score 2):

You should run the autoprefixer (since version 3.2), also see https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15203

Cause your are compiling client side, you can NOT run [this plugin](https://github.com/less/less-plugin-autoprefix). Alternatively you can use [-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/).

Notice that the autoprefixer is part of TB default build process now.

> Thought they were supposed to use mixins internally until v4

Yes, probably. But i seems new added code is not longer prefixed by mixins. Code that used a mixin before v3.2. already, are not replaced before v4.

You can see the above in the `less/carousel.less` file, that contains the following code (reflecting your issue):

```
// WebKit CSS3 transforms for supported devices
@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
  transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Thought they were supposed to use mixins internally until v4.